# 2 DropDownLists on each row of Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, ispostback

I have a gridview that is being dynamically created based on the database.  Some rows of the gridview have 2 DropDownLists, while others do not depending on the item in the row.  The second DropDownList of the row is dynamically created based on the selection of the first DrowpDownMenu.  Everything works as it should except, if you make the selections on the first row, then change the selection of the first DropDownList of the seccond row or click the update button, it will reset the second DropDownList of the first row.  This is obviously due to PostBack.  But I'd like to maintain the selection until all DropDownLists have been selected and I save the changes to the DB.  Any help would be very appreciated.

My Gridview:

[image]

```
    <asp:GridView ID="CartList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" 
        GridLines="Vertical" CellPadding="4" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" 
        OnRowDataBound="CartList_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ProductID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Product.ProductName" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Product.UnitPrice" HeaderText="Price (each)" DataFormatString="{0:c}" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PurchaseQuantity" Width="40" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Size">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Sizeddl" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" 
                        AutoPostBack="true" ForeColor="Black" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Sizeddl_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Color">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ColorNameddl" runat="server" 
                        Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Total">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#: String.Format("{0:c}", ((Convert.ToDouble( Eval("Quantity") )) *  Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Product.UnitPrice"))))%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove Item">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="Remove" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <div>
        <p></p>
        <strong>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelSubtotal" runat="server" Text="SubTotal: "></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSubtotal" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
        </strong>
        <p></p>
        <strong>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelTax" runat="server" Text="Tax Total: "></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTax" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
        </strong>
        <p></p>
        <strong>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelTotalText" runat="server" Text="Order Total: "></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
        </strong>
    </div>
    <br />
    <table>
```

GridView Load:

```
        DataTable rstSize = new DataTable();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (ShoppingCartActions usersShoppingCart = new ShoppingCartActions())
            {
                decimal cartTotal = 0;
                cartTotal = usersShoppingCart.GetTotal();
                if (cartTotal > 0)
                {
                    // Display Total.
                    lblSubtotal.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", usersShoppingCart.GetSubtotal());
                    lblTax.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", usersShoppingCart.GetTax());
                    lblTotal.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", usersShoppingCart.GetTotal());
                }
                else
                {
                    lblSubtotal.Text = "";
                    lblTax.Text = "";
                    lblTotal.Text = "";
                    ShoppingCartTitle.InnerText = "Shopping Cart is Empty";
                    UpdateBtn.Visible = false;
                    CheckoutImageBtn.Visible = false;
                }
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    LoadGrid();
                }
            }
        }
```

```
        void LoadGrid()
        {
            // Load Cart Items.
            using (ShoppingCartActions actions = new ShoppingCartActions())
            {
                var _db = new ProductContext();
                string cartId = actions.GetCartId();
                var cart = _db.ShoppingCartItems.Where(
                c => c.CartId == cartId).ToList();

                // Create DataTable for Colors
                rstSize.Columns.Add("SizeName", typeof(string));
                var row = rstSize.NewRow();
                row["SizeName"] = "S";
                row["SizeName"] = "M";
                row["SizeName"] = "L";
                row["SizeName"] = "XL";
                row["SizeName"] = "2XL";

                CartList.DataSource = cart;
                CartList.DataBind();

                // Hide DropDown Lists for rows that they are not needed for.
                for (int i = 0; i < CartList.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DropDownList sizeDDL = CartList.Rows[i].FindControl("Sizeddl") as DropDownList;
                    DropDownList colorDDL = CartList.Rows[i].FindControl("ColorNameddl") as DropDownList;

                    IOrderedDictionary rowValues = new OrderedDictionary();
                    rowValues = GetValues(CartList.Rows[i]);
                    var _prodID = Convert.ToInt32(rowValues["ProductID"]);
                    var _prod = (from c in _db.Products
                                 where c.ProductID == _prodID
                                 select c.CategoryID).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (_prod != 1)
                    {
                        sizeDDL.Visible = false;
                        colorDDL.Visible = false;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

My RowDataBound:

```
        protected void CartList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DataRowView gData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
                // Populate and select Color from DB.
                DropDownList sizeDDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("Sizeddl");
                sizeDDL.DataSource = rstSize;
                sizeDDL.DataBind();
                sizeDDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Size", "0"));
                sizeDDL.SelectedValue = gData["SizeName"].ToString();

                // Load Color DDL
                var _size = sizeDDL.SelectedItem.Text;
                int _prod = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
                var _db = new ProductContext();
                var qryColor = (from p in _db.ProductAttributes
                                join c in _db.Colors
                                on p.ColorID equals c.ColorID
                                where p.SizeName == _size & p.ProductID == _prod
                                select new { p.ColorID, c.ColorName }).Distinct().ToList();
                DropDownList colorDDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ColorNameddl");
                
                // Create DataTable for Colors
                DataTable rstColor = new DataTable();
                rstColor.Columns.Add("ColorID", typeof(int));
                rstColor.Columns.Add("ColorName", typeof(string));
                foreach(var item in qryColor)
                {
                    var row = rstColor.NewRow();
                    row["ColorID"] = item.ColorID;
                    row["ColorName"] = item.ColorName;
                    rstColor.Rows.Add(row);
                }

                // Bind Color Drop Down List to DataTable.
                colorDDL.DataSource = rstColor;
                colorDDL.DataBind();
                colorDDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Color", "0"));
                colorDDL.SelectedValue = gData["ColorName"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

My SelectedIndexChanged

```
        protected void Sizeddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList sizeDDL = (DropDownList)sender;
            GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)sizeDDL.NamingContainer;

            string strSize = sizeDDL.SelectedItem.Text;
            DropDownList colorDDL = (DropDownList)gRow.FindControl("ColorNameddl");

            if (strSize != "Choose one")
            {
                using (ProductContext context = new ProductContext())
                {
                    int _prodID = Convert.ToInt32(gRow.Cells[0].Text);
                    var _size = sizeDDL.SelectedItem.Text;
                    var qryColor = (from p in context.ProductAttributes
                                    join c in context.Colors
                                    on p.ColorID equals c.ColorID
                                    where p.SizeName == _size & p.ProductID == _prodID
                                    select new { p.ColorID, c.ColorName }).Distinct().ToList();
                    if (qryColor.Count > 0)
                    {
                        colorDDL.DataSource = qryColor;
                        colorDDL.DataTextField = "ColorName";
                        colorDDL.DataValueField = "ColorID";
                        colorDDL.DataBind();
                        colorDDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Color", "0"));
                        colorDDL.Enabled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        colorDDL.Items.Clear();
                        colorDDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("No Colors Available", "0"));
                        colorDDL.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if you make the selections on the first row

By "selections" are we to assume make changes - or select/change a value in the combo boxes, right?

> I'd like to maintain the selection until all DropDownLists have been selected and I save the changes to the DB.

A grid view will and should handle post backs on the page. After all, even outside of the GV, any old button or control can and will cause post-backs.

There is no reason that changes to ANY grid row by users, and that includes drop down lists (DDL) should matter. And operations on one row should not effect operations on other rows. The so called "view" state of the GV is automatic, and for the most part you should not have to worry.

So, it not at all clear why you posted the "add row", since all of this question centers on editing or making changes to the current row. (For us, say next week or whenever, we can look at or deal with the row created, but for now let's concentrate on the changes to a given row, and why for some reason you see effects in other rows - you should not be seeing this.

Tops on the list?

While controls - including a GV can and should handle post-backs without issue?

That is NOT the case if a post-back causes a re-bind of the grid. If that is to occur, then you going have issues.

So, tops on the list?

You left out how/when/where you are loading up the GV (the MOST important part).

Next up?

You do NOT want nor need to show the row PK id in the GV. These numbers not only mean nothing to the end user but it also a security risk - PK row numbers don't need to be displayed, and in fact do not even need to be included in the row markup.  We again can leave that issue for another day, but you can (and should consider) using DataKeys for the row PK id operations. We assume no duplicate PK row id in the database, right? In other words, make sure you have a database row PK "id" in your data.

So, you can in the future, remove that ProductID. GV has a special feature for dealing with the PK row id - and we should be using that. (Datakeys)

OK, now that we cleared up the above?

In the page load event, we need to load the GV, but ONLY on first page load - after that, we can't re-load the GV (bind again), else you WILL lose your changes, and edits to the GV.

Also, you might want to consider a save button at the bottom - to save all gv changes - in place of doing this row by row. (but, one thing at a time here).

So first up, the code to load the GV, should be in page load.

Next up, that code has to ONLY run the first time.

eg:

```
if (!IsPostBack) 
{
    code here to load GV
}
```

Next up? when the GV is loaded with that data, you need to setup the combo box and the cascade. And further more, this setup of each row should occur in the row data bound event.

So, your posted code does look ok, but we missing how/when you load the GV.

And we don't see your save button either. But at this point, I would share your code that loads up the GV - this all important information is missing here.

So edit your question - show how and when you load the grid up - that's missing.

Also, why the row created event being used here to setup a event? Just put the event stub and definition in the markup.

You are free to drop in a plain Jane button, or DDL or whatever into the GV. And you should wire up the events like all other controls.

So, remove that row created event stub - it might be wiring up events for the wrong row - but it not required, and is a high risk adventure.

So, just do this:

[image]

So, for a button, or DDL in the GV? You can't double click on a button (to create a click event), and you can't display the property sheet to add events. But you can in markup just type in the event name, hit "=", and note how above intel-sense pops up a option to create the event. So, add the event that way. And after you select create new event, then you can flip over to code behind - you see the new event stub, and add your code to that stub. The GV uses internal information to wire up each row events - you may well be messing this up.

So, I would remove your row added - as we don't have details about that code and how/when you add a row, but 100% elimination of the row created event, and wiring up a click event will go a long way to elimination of any issues here - this would be especially the case if your row add event "copy's" controls - you might be copy the the DDL object when you do this, and that again will cause issues. In other words you may have the same object for two rows - changes to one will effect the other.

So, dump your row add event, and add the event directly in markup for the ddl as per above.

So, for buttons on each row, or whatever? You can still (and should) use markup to add those events - not code unless no other means exists to do so.

## Edit: Working example

So, say this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" 
    CssClass="table"
    Width="30%" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">

    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Firstname" HeaderText="Firstname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"  />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select Hotel City">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server" Width="120px"  Height="26px"
                    DataTextField = "City"
                    DataValueField = "City"
                    AutoPostback="true" 
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboCity_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    > 
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select Hotel">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboHotels" runat="server" Width="210px"  Height="26px"
                    DataValueField ="ID"
                    DataTextField ="HotelName">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nights"  >
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtNights" runat="server" Style="text-align:right"
                   Text='<%# Eval("Nights") %>' Width="70px" >
               </asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

We will cascade city combo to restrict Hotels in 2nd combo.

So, our code to load:

```
    DataTable rstCity = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid ()
    {
        // load up City list for combo box - all rows (scope = page)
        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT City from City ORDER BY City");
        rstCity = MyRstP(cmdSQL);

        // load up the grid
        cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT * from People ORDER BY FirstName"; 
        GridView1.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

We have this:

[image]

Note how we did NOT risk trying to set the DDLs in the markup - since we cascading - there will be way too many issues.

So, of course we have row data bound - and that sets up the two DDLs. (we setup the cascade AND ALSO set their values.

We have this:

```
   protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView gData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem; // get the row data
            // load the city combo box
            DropDownList cboCity = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("cboCity");
            cboCity.DataSource = rstCity;
            cboCity.DataBind();
            // add blank row for city
            cboCity.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select City", ""));
            cboCity.SelectedValue = gData["City"].ToString();  // set value of Current city

            // now load Hotel combo box - but cascade from above City cbo
            string strSQL = @"Select ID, HotelName From tblHotels WHERE City = @City " +
                            " ORDER BY HotelName";
            SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = gData["HotelCity"].ToString();

            DropDownList cboHotels = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("cboHotels");
            DataTable rstHotels = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
            cboHotels.DataSource = rstHotels;
            cboHotels.DataBind();
            cboHotels.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Hotel", ""));
            // set hotels combo to current selected
            cboHotels.SelectedValue = gData["Hotel_id"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

So, the only part left is the first DDL post-back and cascade code. We have this:

```
    protected void cboCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // city changed, so cascade Hotel cbo
        DropDownList cboCity = (DropDownList)sender;

        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)cboCity.NamingContainer;

        // filter hotels to current city
        string strCity = cboCity.SelectedItem.Text;
        DropDownList cboHotels = (DropDownList)gRow.FindControl("cboHotels");

        if (strCity != "Select City")
        {
            SqlCommand cmdSQL = new 
                SqlCommand(@"SELECT * from tblHotels WHERE City  = @City ORDER BY HotelName");
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = strCity;                
            cboHotels.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
            cboHotels.DataBind();
            cboHotels.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Hotel", ""));
        }
    }
```

So, with above? I don't see how it is possible that some "other" row gets effected here (unless you have some other code that attempts to mess around with the rows, or inserts a row into the GV. If you going to insert a row, then insert at the database level - and re-bind the GV. But, inserting is a separate issue.

Comment: I believe you are confused.  When You make a selection from DDL1 DDL2 is populated from it's datasouce according to which ever is selected in DDL1.  in order for that to happen, AutoPostBack must be set to true, otherwise DDL2 would never populate.  As for the Gridview, it is populated with a datasource at first Page_Load.  The gridview is not the issue at all.  Prior to me adding the DDLs the GridView worked perfectly fine.  IT still does and acts as it should.

Comment: The only problem is the second DDL as it resets to the default on every PostBack.  DDL1 doesn't change at all and in fact stays as it should all the way through to Saving in the Database, as does the quantity TextBox.

Comment: It should not be re-setting. As I stated, dump the row created event - you don't need it, and it just eliminates a possible issue. Put the event define in the markup (OnSelectedIndexChanged) to eliminate this issue - and we get to dump a whole event stub as a bonus. And no, the setting or change of the one DDL in the row should not effect others.  And yes, of course we have auto-postback  = true - no confusing on that issue.  So, if the combo box is re-setting, then there is some other missing information here. I mean, on first GV load, how/when/where do you setup the two DDL's then?

Comment: I just added the GV Load methods I'm using

Comment: And when and where does the loading of GV code get called? I assume on page load inside of the !IsPostBack code stub, right?

Comment: It's actually in the html markup

Comment: I just tried what you said, and it still causes the second DDL to reset.

Comment: The loading of the GV then most likely has to be moved out of the markup - since then you can't control when this occurs.  And I stated to use the on selected index change event - and wire it up in the markup. I'll post a simple working example in a few minutes.

Comment: As per your comment, i did databinding inside a method for the gridview.  removed the databinding from html.  But now it 1) Still changes the second DDL and 2) ignores my method that hides DDLs in rows that they shouldn't be.

Comment: and to be clear, that is with the gridview being loaded in If (!IsPostBack)

Comment: Hum, some other code must be messing around. I just posted a working example/sample - see my edit for some ideas.

Comment: Ok, just updated my post to reflect those changes.  It's now throwing "Unable to cast object of type Entity.DynamicProxies" during RowDataBound, is that due to me needing to use SQL queries for the DB in order for this to work?

Comment: Hum, this would and should work fine with EF. In fact when I use DataRowView during the row databind? You would and could in fact use the base table (class) in place of that, and you would even get intel-sense then. So, it not clear what line in row databound is failing. Row data bound is a great place to hide/show the DDL's, and is a great place to set them up. I actually think some other code - or even the edit code or something else is messing this up. Maybe I'll post the code with EF and linq  as a example - but it should not make much difference here.

Comment: I managed to get it to work, by filling the color drop down with all colors and then disabling those I don’t use depending on size.  But as soon as I click the button that updates the DB to the selections, it saves to the DB but then clears all options from the dropdown

Comment: Hum, I don't see why "colors" would have anything to do with this. And it depends on how your save button works. I don't use the built in GV event model - as I find just a simple ONE save button at the bottom of the grid works a lot better. And I also don't use nor have edit buttons - you can just edit - like all users are used to with any grid of data - say like Excel. But, regardless, I don't see that color or disabling would fix the basic issue - regardless, it looks like you have this working.

Comment: I do have the original issue working.  Now it's really just an issue of getting the second DDL to select a value according to the DB, and not clear out when the user clicks the update button.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the update where the second dropdown now functions correctly.  However, when you click the update button, it will save correctly to the DB, but resets and clears out the second drowpdown list.

Markup:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="CartList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" GridLines="Vertical" CellPadding="4"
        ItemType="GetAGrip.Models.CartItem" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered"
        EnableViewState="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ProductID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Product.ProductName" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Product.UnitPrice" HeaderText="Price (each)" DataFormatString="{0:c}" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PurchaseQuantity" Width="40" runat="server" Text="<%#: Item.Quantity %>"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Size">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Sizeddl" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Sizeddl_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        AutoPostBack="true" ForeColor="Black" SelectedValue="<%#: Item.SizeName %>">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Choose one" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="S" Value="S"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="M" Value="M"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="L" Value="L"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="XL" Value="XL"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="2XL" Value="2XL"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Color">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ColorNameddl" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:Label ID="Templbl" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Total">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#: String.Format("{0:c}", ((Convert.ToDouble(Item.Quantity)) *  Convert.ToDouble(Item.Product.UnitPrice)))%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove Item">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="Remove" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <div>
        <p></p>
        <strong>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelSubtotal" runat="server" Text="SubTotal: "></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSubtotal" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
        </strong>
        <p></p>
        <strong>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelTax" runat="server" Text="Tax Total: "></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTax" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
        </strong>
        <p></p>
        <strong>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelTotalText" runat="server" Text="Order Total: "></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
        </strong>
    </div>
    <br />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="UpdateBtn" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="UpdateBtn_Click" Visible="false" Enabled="false"/>
            </td>
            <th colspan="1">&nbsp
            </th>
            <td>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="CheckoutImageBtn" runat="server"
                    ImageUrl="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif"
                    Width="145" AlternateText="Check out with PayPal"
                    OnClick="CheckoutBtn_Click"
                    BackColor="Transparent" BorderWidth="0" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Page_Load

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadGrid();
            }

            using (ShoppingCartActions usersShoppingCart = new ShoppingCartActions())
            {
                decimal cartTotal = 0;
                cartTotal = usersShoppingCart.GetTotal();
                if (cartTotal > 0)
                {
                    // Display Total.
                    lblSubtotal.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", usersShoppingCart.GetSubtotal());
                    lblTax.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", usersShoppingCart.GetTax());
                    lblTotal.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", usersShoppingCart.GetTotal());
                }
                else
                {
                    lblSubtotal.Text = "";
                    lblTax.Text = "";
                    lblTotal.Text = "";
                    ShoppingCartTitle.InnerText = "Shopping Cart is Empty";
                    UpdateBtn.Visible = false;
                    CheckoutImageBtn.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Load Grid, Load Second DropDown List & Hide DDLs on rows they shouldn't be on:

```
        void LoadGrid()
        {
            GetShoppingCartItems();
            CartList.DataSource = GetShoppingCartItems();
            CartList.DataBind();

            var _db = new ProductContext();
            for (int i = 0; i < CartList.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DropDownList sizeDDL = CartList.Rows[i].FindControl("Sizeddl") as DropDownList;
                DropDownList colorDDL = CartList.Rows[i].FindControl("ColorNameddl") as DropDownList;

                var _colors = (from c in _db.Colors
                               select c.ColorName).Distinct().ToList();
                colorDDL.DataSource = _colors;
                colorDDL.DataBind();
                colorDDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Color", "0"));
                colorDDL.SelectedIndex = 0;
                foreach (ListItem item in colorDDL.Items)
                {
                    item.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
                }

                IOrderedDictionary rowValues = new OrderedDictionary();
                rowValues = GetValues(CartList.Rows[i]);
                var _prodID = Convert.ToInt32(rowValues["ProductID"]);
                var _prod = (from c in _db.Products
                             where c.ProductID == _prodID
                             select c.CategoryID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (_prod != 1)
                {
                    sizeDDL.Visible = false;
                    colorDDL.Visible = false;
                }
            }

        }
```

GetShoppingCartItems Method:

```
        public List<CartItem> GetShoppingCartItems()
        {
            ShoppingCartActions actions = new ShoppingCartActions();
            return actions.GetCartItems();
        }
```

UpdateCartItems Method

```
        public List<CartItem> UpdateCartItems()
        {
            using (ShoppingCartActions usersShoppingCart = new ShoppingCartActions())
            {
                String cartId = usersShoppingCart.GetCartId();

                ShoppingCartActions.ShoppingCartUpdates[] cartUpdates = new ShoppingCartActions.ShoppingCartUpdates[CartList.Rows.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < CartList.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    IOrderedDictionary rowValues = new OrderedDictionary();
                    rowValues = GetValues(CartList.Rows[i]);
                    cartUpdates[i].ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(rowValues["ProductID"]);

                    CheckBox cbRemove = new CheckBox();
                    cbRemove = (CheckBox)CartList.Rows[i].FindControl("Remove");
                    cartUpdates[i].RemoveItem = cbRemove.Checked;

                    TextBox quantityTextBox = new TextBox();
                    quantityTextBox = (TextBox)CartList.Rows[i].FindControl("PurchaseQuantity");
                    cartUpdates[i].PurchaseQuantity = Convert.ToInt16(quantityTextBox.Text.ToString());

                    DropDownList sizeDropDown = new DropDownList();
                    sizeDropDown = (DropDownList)CartList.Rows[i].FindControl("Sizeddl");
                    cartUpdates[i].SizeName = sizeDropDown.Text;

                    DropDownList colorDropDown = new DropDownList();
                    colorDropDown = (DropDownList)CartList.Rows[i].FindControl("ColorNameddl");
                    cartUpdates[i].ColorName = colorDropDown.Text;

                }
                usersShoppingCart.UpdateShoppingCartDatabase(cartId, cartUpdates);
                CartList.DataBind();
                lblSubtotal.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", usersShoppingCart.GetSubtotal());
                lblTax.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", usersShoppingCart.GetTax());
                lblTotal.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", usersShoppingCart.GetTotal());
                return usersShoppingCart.GetCartItems();
            }
        }
```

GetValues Dictionary

```
        public static IOrderedDictionary GetValues(GridViewRow row)
        {
            IOrderedDictionary values = new OrderedDictionary();
            foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.Visible)
                {
                    // Extract values from the cell.
                    cell.ContainingField.ExtractValuesFromCell(values, cell, row.RowState, true);
                }
            }
            return values;
        }
```

Update Button Click

```
        protected void UpdateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CartList.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                UpdateCartItems();
            }
            Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
        }
```

RowDataBound

```
        protected void CartList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DataRowView gData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;  // get row data.
                // load the color Drop Down List.
                DropDownList sizeDDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("Sizeddl");

                sizeDDL.SelectedValue = gData["SizeName"].ToString();

                //// Load Color DDL
                var _size = sizeDDL.SelectedItem.Text;
                int _prod = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
                var _db = new ProductContext();
                var qryColor = (from p in _db.ProductAttributes
                                join c in _db.Colors
                                on p.ColorID equals c.ColorID
                                where p.SizeName == _size & p.ProductID == _prod
                                select new { p.ColorID, c.ColorName }).Distinct().ToList();

                DropDownList colorDDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ColorNameddl");

                // Bind Color Drop Down List to DataTable.
                foreach (ListItem item in colorDDL.Items)
                {
                    if (qryColor.Any(c => c.ColorName == item.ToString()))
                    {
                        item.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
                colorDDL.SelectedValue = gData["ColorName"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

1st Dropdown SelectedIndexChanged

```
        protected void Sizeddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList sizeDDL = (DropDownList)sender;
            GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)sizeDDL.NamingContainer;

            string strSize = sizeDDL.SelectedItem.Text;
            DropDownList colorDDL = (DropDownList)gRow.FindControl("ColorNameddl");

            if (strSize != "Choose one")
            {
                using (ProductContext context = new ProductContext())
                {
                    int _prodID = Convert.ToInt32(gRow.Cells[0].Text);
                    var _size = sizeDDL.SelectedItem.Text;
                    var qryColor = (from p in context.ProductAttributes
                                    join c in context.Colors
                                    on p.ColorID equals c.ColorID
                                    where p.SizeName == _size & p.ProductID == _prodID
                                    select new { p.ColorID, c.ColorName }).Distinct().ToList();

                    if (qryColor.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (ListItem item in colorDDL.Items)
                        {
                            if (qryColor.Any(c => c.ColorName == item.ToString()))
                            {
                                item.Enabled = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                item.Enabled = false;
                            }
                        }
                        colorDDL.Items[0].Enabled = true;
                        colorDDL.Enabled = true;
                        colorDDL.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        colorDDL.SelectedIndex = 0;
                        colorDDL.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Anyplace you see a method that is not above, it's because it's a method in my Logic file to handle database queries for the whole application.